# I would like to calculate total clocked in hours by date from a list with multiple entries

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am making a spreadsheet that calculates total clocked in time for any specific date as selected from a dropdown menu. However, there are multiple rows in the table per each date, though there would only be a clock-in and clock-out on the first and last entries for each date, respectively. Example below:

[image]

which would output in `h:mm` format using the date as the reference variable like this

| SELECT DATE | 8/24 |
| --- | --- |
| Time clocked in for date | 10:03 |

Since the entries are not next to each other in the code, I encountered difficulties writing expressions by date, and since sometimes there are blank spots, I am not sure how to output the time spent working for each date. I am using Excel 2019 365 edition.

Comment: Shouldn't it be 10:03?

Comment: If you are looking for total clocked time, if am not wrong here. Re: as per your post `I am making a spreadsheet that calculates total clocked in time for any specific date as selected from a dropdown menu`

Comment: Lots of questions on this one:  Will there ever be more than 1 clock in or clock out for a date (clock out for lunch/breaks)?  Do you need to handle missed punches (clock in but no clock out or clock out but no clock in)?  Do you have overnight shifts where the clock in would be on one day, but the clock out would be on the next day?  Are you going to have more than one person using this so that you have separate out the data by user?

Comment: Second that @FrankBall. Even I had the same question. This post is not clear, the subject says for **total time** and the first four lines as well where as below it says `Time clocked in for date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, as per the post explanations, then.

> *I am making a spreadsheet that calculates **total** clocked in time for any specific date as selected from a dropdown menu. However, there are multiple rows in the table per each date, though there would only be a clock-in and clock-out on the first and last entries for each date, respectively.*

[image]

---

So for total clocked in time for any specific date, I would use <kbd>MOD( )</kbd> and <kbd>SUM( )</kbd> function or <kbd>SUMPRODUCT( )</kbd> if not using `MS365`. That said the formula used in cell <kbd>F2</kbd>

```
=MOD(
     SUM((F1=TimeTable[Date])*TimeTable[Clock Out])-
     SUM((F1=TimeTable[Date])*TimeTable[Clock In]),1)
```

---

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this with `FILTER`. Solution only works if clock in and clock out always happens in same day (no night shifts):

```
=FILTER(Table1[Clock out],(Table1[Clock out]<>"")*(Table1[Date]=F1))-FILTER(Table1[Clock in],(Table1[Clock in]<>"")*(Table1[Date]=F1))
```

Result:

[image]

Don't forget to format `F2` cell.

Answer (score 1):

If there is only 1 Clock-In time per date, and only 1 Clock-Out time per date, then that time will be the only non-zero entry for that date.

Which means you can just use [the `MAXIFS` function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/maxifs-function-dfd611e6-da2c-488a-919b-9b6376b28883), like so:

```
=MAXIFS($C:$C, $A:$A, $F$1) - MAXIFS($B:$B, $A:$A, $F$1)
```

(Where Column A is your list of dates, Column B is the list of Clock-In times, Column C is the list of Clock-Out times, and Cell F1 contains the date you are trying to compare)

If you had multiple clock-in and clock-out times per date, then this would only give you the last entries for each.  However, you could get the *earliest* with [the `MINIFS` function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/minifs-function-6ca1ddaa-079b-4e74-80cc-72eef32e6599), and a slight modification:

```
=MAXIFS($C:$C, $A:$A, $F$1) - MINIFS($B:$B, $A:$A, $F$1, $B:$B, ">0")
```

(This will calculate the time between the *first* clock-in and the *last* clock-out for the day.)

Comment: It makes sense, and you have covered all the options. Nice =)

Answer (score 0):

As commented by 11222393 the answer is different from the suggested outcome in the question, but this could do the trick in Office 365:

```
=LET(d, (Table1[Date]=F1),
     TOCOL(REPT(Table1[Clock Out],d)/1,3)-
     TOCOL(REPT(Table1[Clock In],d)/1,3))
```

Where `F1` holds the date value you search for.

[image]

Comment: Three flavours. I like Mayukh's solution best.

Comment: But the question is not right. There are some questions within questions. I have never thought of using `TOCOL()` in this way. Nice Approach.